# Android 12 Device Owner App Not Booting Correct Launcher

Tags: android

Previously my QR code install with Device Policies as below used to automatically set the Home Launcher after provisioning

```
{
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.peachss.mdm/.PeachMDMAdminReceiver",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "kDxUqVh95IjPhhRx....",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "....",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION": true,
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED": false,
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {}
}
```

I have made the changes as per posts found on Stack Over Flow I added the following activities

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.peachss.mdm.AdminPolicyComplianceActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.peachss.mdm.GetProvisioningModeActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.GET_PROVISIONING_MODE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
            android:name="com.peachss.mdm.ProvisioningSuccessActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.PROVISIONING_SUCCESSFUL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now my installation of my Device Owner App is working again, however it no longer sets my Home Lauhcer Automatically and it immediately goes into the normal home launcher, then you first have to open the Device Owner App for it to take over.

How do you set the Home Launcher Automatically After Provisioning is completed

I have tried the following in DeviceAdminReceiver

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var action = intent.Action;
        switch (action)
        {
            case "android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE":
                context.StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SplashActivity)));
                break;
            default:
                base.OnReceive(context, intent);
                break;
        }

    }
```

I have also tried to use

```
    public override void OnProfileProvisioningComplete(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        context.StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SplashActivity)));
        base.OnProfileProvisioningComplete(context, intent);
    }
```